# Find out which method consumes less memory on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8.1

I have two libraries which do exactly the same thing - generate a PNG file from a `WriteableBitmap`.

How do I know which one consumes less memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has great [Performance and Diagnostics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/02/11/combining-tools-in-the-performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) tools which you can find in the "Analyze" menu in the menu bar on top. Using these tools you can record CPU usage, memory usage, UI responsiveness and battery usage of your app. Interact with your app while recording and analyze it afterwards. This should be the most realistic way of finding out what behaves better.